# What is a good examples of a sustainable writing ball-point pen?

Tags: product-design

What are the design principles of a sustainable writing ball-point pen?
Is there any academic work or industry standards on sustainability of writing ball-point pens?

Comment: Product-recommendations are off-topic on almost all StackExchange websites, including this one. This is because they are 'list'-questions and because they tend to become spam magnets. The only exception is if there are only 1 or 2 products that would qualify to the mentioned criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at refillable pens, where you do not have to throw away the whole pen if it's finished, but can just replace the inside. You can buy them in most office stores and are not very expensive (often less than 1 dollar/euro/pound for a refill).
A lot of pens are refillable so it's worth looking if you may already have one laying around!

Comment: Do you mean replacing the ink "cartridge"? Or are there pens where you can actually refill the ink itself?

Comment: Yes you have the ones with cartridges, but you can also buy rollerball pens that are refillable like fountain pens, so you can refill them with actual ink, but have not tried those yet. An example of this is the J Herbin refillable rollerball pen, but I think that might write a bit differently than a 'normal' ball point pen